# Cordova HTTP Plugin how to disable timeout?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-advanced-http

the default timeout is 60, if I set timeout to 0 it will still work, how to disable it completely?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can disable timeout on the plugin, but you can use `cordova.plugin.http.setRequestTimeout(number_in_seconds);`

Just put a high number in `number_in_seconds` should do the trick

Comment: that's what I want to avoid... it's not a solution :(

Comment: As far as I know, you can't disable it.